# Unable to use Azure Document DB-REST API using Ajax call

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am using Azure DocumentDB with REST API and trying to call the API from HTML page using Ajax requests. But I found that authorization headers are not getting added in a request. After searching, a lot, I found that it may be a CORS issue. Same request works well when POSTMAN tool is used. Security header got set in this case.

Comment: seems old question but want to mention that to get around this one can setup the DocumentDB REST API's on APIM (Azure API Management Gateway) and use the end-point provided by APIM on your client side.

Comment: @GopiKolla thanks for the tip. I couldn't find API Management Gateway in the services on azure portal. Do you happen to know what the new name is?

Comment: @mireilleraad it would be under integration and the name of the service is "API Management"

Answer (score 3):

You're correct! DocumentDB REST API can't be called using AJAX from the browser because of CORS and right now it is not possible to configure CORS settings for a DocumentDB account.

Comment: I wish this was written in blinking letters on the documentation page